# checking for string on javascript event happening

Tags: javascript

I've been looking around for this but cant get my finger on it for a while now.
I have a javascript running on a website that is generating messages with a particular string. I want to create an app that checks to see if this particular string exists on the element the javascript is generating. How can I do this? I've built a script that reads the webpage HTML and can check for a string within the HTML itself but cannot do this with the javascript since the message elements are being generated after a second or so and are not in the webpage source code.

You can see an example of the javascript elements I need to work with on [openbook.etoro.com](http://openbook.etoro.com)

I have no relation or connection with this company, its just the best example I could find.
In this website there a script generating messages about what trades some people traded with some info about how long ago (the string I'm looking for).

How can this be done?

Comment: wont a timer event help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that come to mind.  One figure out what function or event is loading the new elements and then run your function afterwards.  Or use `setInterval(function(){checkForString()},5000);` which would run every five seconds.